# Minimal polynomial of an inverse given the min polynomial of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:**
Given that $A$ is an invertible matrix and $m_A(x)=a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n$ find $m_{A^{-1}}$.

**Thought**:
If I put A in the polynomial then it's equal to 0, then I multiply the entire equation by (A^-1)^n , then I get some kind of polynomial: $a_n+a_{n-1}x+...+a_0x^n$ - I know that $A^{-1}$ makes it become zero, but how do I know if it's indeed the minimal?

Comment: Let $m_{A^{-1}}$ be the minimal polynomial of $A^{-1}$. You know that divides $a_n + a_{n-1}x +\dotsc + a_0 x^n$. Now interchange the roles.

Answer (score 2):

An exercise for you that may help you here:

If in some field $\;\Bbb F\;$ we have that $\;\alpha\neq 0\;$ is a root of $\;a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_nx^n\in\Bbb F[x]\;$ , then $\;\alpha^{-1}\;$ is a root of $\;a_n+a_{n-1}x+\ldots+a_1x^{n-1}+a_0x^{n}\;$.

Comment: Could you give a hint as to why one can switch the scalars?

Comment: @Alex Do it: if $$a_0+a_1\alpha+\ldots+a_n\alpha^n=0$$ then multiply both sides by $\;\alpha^{-1}\;$ and check what happens...